# Click Events Stop Working

Tags: linux, hardware, mouse, xinput

Problem occurs both on Ubuntu 18.04 and Arch Linux.

After about 5 minutes of booting into my OS, click events from the touchpad and external mouse stop working. Scroll events will behave oddly - sometimes switching to horizontal scrolling and sometimes not working at all.

I've tested with both `xev` and `evtest` and tried disabling and enabling the trackpad with `xinput`. Click events are registered in `evtest` but are not found in `xev`.

The fact that this occurs both in Ubuntu 18.04 and Arch makes me think this is a hardware issue, but I have hit a dead end in trying to debug this. Does anyone have any advice or suggestions?

Laptop is a Lenovo Thinkpad p50s. If any other hardware specs are required just let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't really want to talk about this, but I noticed I had a second usb mouse plugged in that I had completely forgot about that was causing the issue.